# magento enterprise install : redirection to a wrong install path

Tags: magento, nginx, php

I have imported locally a magento enterprise project , created a virtual host for it.

On my navigator,

```
  mydomain.com
```

makes an automatic redirection to

```
    http://www.mydomain.com/index.php/install/
```

giving a

```
   unknown adress error
```

Is this redirection a normal behaviour?

what could be wrong?

the server nginx ( ubuntu / nginx / php5-fpm ) log gives no error

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but try to check your database whether all tables are imported correctly. Also check your app/etc/local.xml file where database connection credentials are placed into